# How to run Django management command on Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have deployed my Django application on azure app function. Is there a way to run the management commands as below remotely?

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Open KUDU site of your web app(App Service=>Advanced Tools=>Go).  Select SSH and connection will be established, Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/7XdSzrs.png). Activate virtual environment using the command(ex: `source /antenv/bin/activate`), Run the commands `pip install -r requirements.txt`, 
`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @PravallikaKV couldn't find it, is it possible on azure function apps?

Comment: Which hosting plan you have used to create function app(Consumption, Functions premium/App Service Plan)?

Comment: @PravallikaKV I am using consumption plan.

Comment: AFAIK, it is possible in Azure App Service. I will check and update if it is possible in function apps.

Comment: I believe you need to deploy your application to [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli).

Comment: @PravallikaKV but I won't be able to take adavantage of serverless capabilities of azure function app right?

Comment: Can you provide your code if possible and deployment process, like how you deployed your application?

Comment: @PravallikaKV my deployed django app is working on azure function app. But for migration and commands i didn't find any clue. I want to use serverless model.

Comment: We cannot run the commands in Consumption plan-Azure functions. Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524563/serverless-django-using-azure-functions) if it helps (or) try dockerizing function and run the custom command by adding your command in the docker file.

Comment: @PravallikaKV Writing a specific function to handle management commands and restricting that function from accessing publicly is the way as far as I know.